# Identify the first instance of a duplicate in a column

Tags: r, data.table

I have a column named 'A'

| **A** |
| --- |
| Dog |
| Cat |
| Dog |
| Sheep |

I want to create a new column, called 'Keep' that has a 1 for the first instance of a duplicate as well as all unique values

| A | Keep |
| --- | --- |
| Dog | 1 |
| Cat | 1 |
| Dog | 0 |
| Sheep | 1 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `duplicated` :

```
df$Keep <- as.integer(!duplicated(df$A))
```

If you want to do this using `data.table` :

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, Keep := as.integer(!duplicated(A))]
df

#       A Keep
#1:   Dog    1
#2:   Cat    1
#3:   Dog    0
#4: Sheep    1
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(A = c("Dog", "Cat", "Dog", "Sheep")), 
      class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```